# Predicting Naive Bayes model in R on a test data with a single record

Tags: r, machine-learning, discrete-data, naive-bayes

I built a naivebayes model using the Housevotes84 data(discrete data) in mlbench package-

```
model <- naiveBayes(Class~., data=HouseVotes84)
```

I took one record from the data to predict the model.
Irrespective of which record it is the model always provides the output- "Democrats".

```
housevotes_test <- read.csv("path")

predict(model, housevotes_test[1,])
[1] democrat
```

I then tried a test data with 2 records- 1 wrt republicans and the other wrt Democrats.
I find that while predicting the model on this test data the model classifies accurately.

Here are my questions-

1. Why does the model always classify the test record into "Democrats" when only a single record is given in test data?
2. Is the classification dependent on the target variable? Since it classifies the test records accurately when the data consists of atleast 1 record pertaining to "democrats".

I am not sure if the code is wrong. So please point out where the error is or provide an explanation for this mis-classification when only 1 record exists in test data.

Please try this experiment and please help me with finding an answer to this.

Comment: Which naiveBayes do you use? This from `e1071`? What is your `housevotes_test`?

Comment: I used the NaiveBayes from e1071 package and the data HouseVotes_84 from mlbench package. I created a new data called housevotes_test which contains only 1 record. This is my test data. Irrespective of this 1 record in test data is "Republicans" or "Democrats" the naive Bayes always classifies it into "Democrats". Please let me know if you have any other clarifications